# Word for a command in a business-to-business transaction

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider two companies already being in business; having some sort of contract. Now company A officially orders company B to do something. (E.g. destroy some documents, which company B stores for company A)

What is a good word for this command?

**Command** does not seem fitting in a business context. **Request** might be better, but feels a bit weak, because company B *has* to comply under the existing contract. **Order**—I feel—does mean something different in a business context (as opposed to in a military context). An **order** can be placed, e.g. and then some delivery of goods is expected, but maybe my own experience as a consumer is simply too narrow?

I would prefer one short word if possible. Usage in a sentence would be, e.g.:

> Your command has been submitted successfully.

**Destruction order** would be another possibility (though not as short as I would like). There I really can not say if it fits.

Comment: ***instruction(s)***

Comment: Company A: "Please immediately initiate the destruction of our records." Company B: "Your records have been destroyed."

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That sounds good.

Comment: @MarkHubbard: True, but I need the noun :-)

Comment: @Mark that sounds very destructive.

Comment: @marcellothearcane True, but that seems to be the usual term in this business.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps [**instruction**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/instruction) in this context. Lexico says

> **instruction**
>   NOUN
>
> **1** (often **instructions**) A direction or order.
>   *I have sent an instruction to our solicitor.*

When I was involved in the building industry, the official term for a written direction from the Architect to the builder was an "Architect's Instruction."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was already preparing this before I read your comment.

Comment: Well, you certainly added value with the archetypal example *an **instruction** to our **solicitor***.